# how to show two error message for multiple duplicates record in apex trigger

Tags: trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger, duplicate-value, findduplicates

My requirement In contact object I have two fields Apple__c and orange__c, if I create contact with the duplicate values of existing values in Apple__c and orange__c fields need to throw an error for two separate fields. when I fill the duplicate value only in orange__c need to throw an error only in orange__c filed same Scenario for Apple__c filed too.

I have tried this code but unable to show two separate error for two fields

```
    trigger PreventDuplicateContacts on Contact (before insert) {
Set <String> AppleSet = new Set<String>();
Set <String> OrangeSet = new Set<String>();
for (contact con:trigger.new) {
AppleSet .add(con.Apple__c );
OrangeSet .add(con.orange__c);
}

List <Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
contactlist = [SELECT Apple__c,orange__cFROM Contact WHERE Apple__c  IN :AppleSet  OR orange__c IN :OrangeSet];
for (contact con:trigger.new) {
If (contactList.size() > 0) {
 con.orange__c.adderror( 'Duplicate Contact Found. Use Existing Contact.' );
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the platform's build in [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_map_of_reference.htm&type=5) can achieve what you want? Way easier to set up and much more likely to be correct than once-off trigger logic.

Comment: I need to show filed wise error msg when I enter the duplicate values with specific filed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find duplicate you need to loop through the two lists at the same time: first list with your new records (from Trigger.new) and second list with existing records (contactList).
This part looks good in your example.

When you have two lists to compare you create a nested loop.

```
for (contact newCont : Trigger.new) {
    for (Contact existingCont : contactList) {
        if (newCont.Orange__c == existingCont.Orange__c) {
            newCont.Orange__c.addError( 'Duplicate Contact Found. Use Existing Contact with Id ' + existingCont.Id);
        } else if (newCont.Apple__c == existingCont.Apple__c) {
            newCont.Apple__c.addError( 'Duplicate Contact Found. Use Existing Contact with Id ' + existingCont.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

So you take new contact and loop through a list of existing contacts comparing Orange__c field. If condition for Orange__c if false, then check next field - Apple__c. You may notice that in error message I also added Id value of an exising record.

Important: please be aware, that nested loops may cause performance degradation if the list of records to compare is very big. You may consider to add WHERE statement to the query (contactList in your case) to limit number of contacts to compare.

Comment: I have small doubt when the orange filed does not contain duplicate values and apple fields have duplicate values then the error should throw in the apple filed only, not in the orange filed because the orange field has a fresh value not duplicate. I need like this answer, possible @Roman

Comment: @user83806 I have updated the code example - so if the Orange__c field is fine, then check next field - Apple__c and so on (you may check other fields as well).

Comment: If it is really necessary to build something, be very aware of the 50,000 row governor limit in orgs. A simple solution may work now, but then in say a year's time when the volume of data has grown your trigger will break any insert done for Contact in the org. You will not be popular then.

Comment: I only put in example the part where we have nested loop. In your code you already have initialization of contactList: 
List <Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
contactlist = [SELECT Apple__c,orange__cFROM Contact WHERE Apple__c  IN :AppleSet  OR orange__c IN :OrangeSet];

Comment: Thanks, @RomanD it worked very well. appreciate:)